# Perl: basic question, function functionality

Tags: perl, heredoc

What does this function do?

```
    sub MyDigit {
       return <<END;
       0030\t0039
       END
    }
```

Comment: What happened when you invoked it?

Comment: It’s defining a character class comprising the ASCII digits only, for use in regular expressions. See my answer. PS: Shouldn’t that be written [Le_Cœur](http://translate.google.com/#en|fr|Where%20is%20my%20heart%3F), *n’est-ce pas?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's called a ["here-document"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3CEOF), and is used for breaking strings up over multiple lines as an alternative to concatenation or list operations:

```
print "this is ",
    "one line when printed, ",
    "because print takes multiple ",
    "arguments and prints them all!\n";
print "however, you can also " .
    "concatenate strings together " .
    "and print them all as one string.\n";

print <<DOC;
But if you have a lot of text to print,
you can use a "here document" and create
a literal string that runs until the
delimiter that was declared with <<.
DOC
print "..and now we're back to regular code.\n";
```

You can read more about here-documents in the manual: see [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3CEOF).

Comment: Note that the OP's `END` is not lined up. As a result, the OP's code does not contain a valid heredoc.

Comment: @Sinan: I was assuming that was a typo in transcription, but it is certainly reasonable to check if that is in fact the case.

Comment: @Sinan: See my answer. Everybody missed what’s really going on here!

Answer (score 7):

You’ve all missed the point!

It’s defining a user-defined property for use in `\p{MyDigit}` and `\P{MyDigit}` using regular expressions.

It’s like these:

```
  sub InKana {
      return <<'END';
  3040    309F
  30A0    30FF
  END
  }
```

Alternatively, you could define it in terms of existing property names:

```
  sub InKana {
      return <<'END';
  +utf8::InHiragana
  +utf8::InKatakana
  END
  }
```

You can also do set subtraction using a "C<->" prefix.  Suppose you only
wanted the actual characters, not just the block ranges of characters.
You could weed out all the undefined ones like this:

```
  sub IsKana {
      return <<'END';
  +utf8::InHiragana
  +utf8::InKatakana
  -utf8::IsCn
  END
  }
```

You can also start with a complemented character set using the "C" prefix:

```
  sub IsNotKana {
      return <<'END';
  !utf8::InHiragana
  -utf8::InKatakana
  +utf8::IsCn
  END
  }
```

I figure I must be right, since I’m speaking *ex camelis*. :)

Comment: What namespace does this function have to live in for this to be useful?

Comment: @Ether: Whichever one you specify: `\p{Some::Function}` is in the `%Some::` namespace, whereas `\p{Function}` is in the ‘current’ package, for certain definitions of current.

Answer (score 2):

It uses something called a [Here Document](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/syntax/here_document.html) to return a string "0030\t0039"

Answer (score 2):

It returns the string `"0030\t0039\n"` (`\t` being a tab and `\n` a newline that is being added because the line ends in a newline (obviously)).

```
<<FOO
sometext
FOO
```

Is a so-called heredoc, a way to conveniently write multi-line strings (though here it is used with only one line).

Comment: Isn't there some modifier you can add to make the `\t` literal? I seem to remember needing to put a single quote somewhere...

Comment: @Cameron: from the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#<<EOF): "Single quotes indicate the text is to be treated literally with no interpolation of its content. This is similar to single quoted strings except that backslashes have no special meaning". So you need to say `<<'FOO'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can help yourself by trying a simple experiment:

```
C:\Temp> cat t.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

print MyDigit();

sub MyDigit {
    return <<END;
    0030\t0039
END
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> t | xxd
0000000: 2020 2020 3030 3330 0930 3033 390d 0a        0030.0039..
```

Now, in your case, the `END` is not lined up at the beginning of the line, so you should have gotten the message:

```
Can't find string terminator "END" anywhere before EOF at …
```

Comment: Well yes, but if you really are going to deliver a lesson on heredox, I think my dequeuing strategy in [unichars](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars),  [uninames](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames), [uniprops](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops), and even [leo](http://training.perl.com/scripts/leo) makes for the cleanest looking heredox. But really, you guys all missed what the function is really doing: it’s creating a property that only matches ASCII digits. Must’ve been before `\p{POSIX_Digit}` appeared the v5.12 release.

Comment: @tchrist I think it should be `deQ`